# Unable to render a Visualforce page during a login flow

Tags: visualforce, partner-portal, loginflow

I want to render a pdf so the partner user during the login flow, before he can access the partner site, can preview the information that he fulfilled in the previous screens.

The pdf is generated thanks to an aura component that has inside a iframe tag that calls a visualforce page.

The aura component works fine, in fact if I insert the flow inside the partner site the pdf is correctly visualized. as you can see:

[image: the flow inside the partner site]

Instead, inside the login flow the visualforce page will not render probably for security reasons, this is what appears:

[image]

Is there a way to make this visualforce page available during the login flow?

**I already set all the necessary permissions to make the visualforce page available for the partner user in the site** indeed the vf page is available inside the partner site

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you granted permission for the page in the profile for the underlying Site; that is the one that applies before login. That profile is not in the normal profiles list; instead you access it via the Site details.

Comment: Hi Keith, thanks for the reach, for privacy reasons I cannot post the site visualforce pages available related list but the page is already in there, also in public access the profile has access to the site

Comment: Have you also configured your aura component for [guest access](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/ltng:allowGuestAccess/documentation)?

Comment: Unfortunately for my case an aura app is not available for flow screens, I can use only aura components. But I find this problem strange cause for tests purpose I gave access to guest users both visualforce page and controller and also edit access on contact, I dont have any clue why is doing this